# How do I read/write files to/from iDevice?

Tags: java, file, mp3, ipod

Is there any simple library for iOS devices (i.e. iPod/iPad/iPhone)?

The specific thing I need to do is transfer an mp3 file to a connected iPod, if anyone has a code snippet for that or something. I don't see a way to do this with the file system, as I don't see how to find my iPod in it. I'm thinking I might need to use it as a media device somehow?

Thanks! :)

PS: I was able to find [libipod](http://libipod.sourceforge.net/), but this is written for c++, and I don't wish to use JNI

Comment: @gigadot I don't mean run java on it, read the second half of the question. I want to transfer a file from a computer, with an iPod plugged in, to the iPod

Comment: Not sure which version of iTunes you are running. One way might be configure your iPod to be in disk mode and start writing data. http://ipod.about.com/od/storingfilesandbackup/ss/ipod_storage.htm

Comment: @SathishJayapal Should've specified iPod Touch, not iPod, so I can't use it as disk mode. And I don't think that's what I want anyways; I want it to show up in my iPod's Music, not just store it randomly somewhere in my iPod